# MongoDB check for Collection before creating it

Tags: php, mongodb, collections

I am creating an install script, but I want to make sure that the collections that I am installing are not already being used by another program.

I am wondering is there a PHP function that returns 0 or 1 if the collection exists in the database?

I know I could do a find search, using the collection, however I would prefer not having to do a find search to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`db.getCollectionNames()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/)

Also, here's a [php reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getcollectionnames.php).